# What is the correct way to downvote

Tags: discussion, markdown, down-votes

I did down vote an answer with comments. I get -1 reputation. That is not my primary concern, I am just trying to understand the correct way of down vote.

[image]

Comment: Some suggestions can be found in [this SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question "When is it justifiable to downvote a question?") and [this MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers "Why do you cast downvotes on answers?"). As for the -1, you always get it when you downvote an answer (as opposed to a question, downvoting which is free).

Comment: also see "[The Value of Downvoting, or, How Hacker News Gets It Wrong](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/09/the-value-of-downvoting-or-how-hacker-news-gets-it-wrong/)"